# React Password submit validation

Tags: reactjs, validation, passwords

I am using React typescript for my app. For styling I used [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/). I have created a global input component where type is  `text` and `password`. I have made a couple of form validation. my email validation and password confirmation validations work fine. I have made one password length validation when the user will type then it will display that `password is too small` as an error, My logic works fine but when I click the submit button less than 8 characters, it still able to accept the form. I don't know how to prevent that submit the form if it is less than 8 characters.

I share my code in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/password-validation-forked-7kfb8?file=/src/App.tsx).

**This is form component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { TextInput } from "./input";

export default function App() {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    email: ``,
    password: ``,
    passwordConfirmation: ``,
    loading: false,
    accountCreationSuccessful: false,
    errorPasswordMessage: ``,
    errorEmailMessage: ``,
    passwordLength: ``
  });

  //destructure the state
  const {
    email,
    password,
    passwordConfirmation,
    loading,
    accountCreationSuccessful,
    errorPasswordMessage,
    errorEmailMessage,
    passwordLength
  } = formState;

  const isPasswordValid = (password: any, passwordConfirmation: any) => {
    if (!password || !passwordConfirmation) return false;
    return password === passwordConfirmation;
  };

  const isEmailValid = (value: any) => {
    const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return emailRegex.test(value);
  };

  const sendForm = (payload: any) => {
    return fetch(
      "https://run.mocky.io/v3/03659a5b-fed5-4c5f-b8d0-4b277e902ed3",
      {
        method: `POST`,
        headers: {
          Accept: `application/json`,
          "Content-Type": `application/json`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
      }
    );
  };

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    let passwordError = "";

    if (e.target.id === "password" && password.length < 7) {
      passwordError = "Password is too short";
    }

    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
      passwordLength: passwordError //In here it display the error
    });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      errorPasswordMessage: isPasswordValid(password, passwordConfirmation)
        ? ``
        : `Upps sorry Password did not match `,
      errorEmailMessage: isEmailValid(email) ? `` : `Upps sorry wrong email  `
    });

    if (
      !isPasswordValid(formState.password, formState.passwordConfirmation) ||
      !isEmailValid(formState.email)
    ) {
      return;
    }

    const response = await sendForm({
      email: formState.email,
      password: formState.password
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      setFormState({
        ...formState,
        accountCreationSuccessful: true,
        email: ``,
        password: ``,
        passwordConfirmation: ``
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TextInput
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={handleChange}
        id="email"
        label="Email"
        required
        error={errorEmailMessage}
      />
      <TextInput
        type="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={handleChange}
        id="password"
        required
        label="password"
        isPassword
        error={passwordLength} //Password lenght error
      />
      <TextInput
        type="password"
        value={passwordConfirmation}
        onChange={handleChange}
        id="passwordConfirmation"
        required
        label="Confirm password"
        isPassword
        error={errorPasswordMessage}
      />
      <button
        type="submit"
        name="action"
        onClick={onSubmit}
        disabled={!formState.email}
      >
        {loading ? `loading...` : `save`}
      </button>

      {accountCreationSuccessful && !loading ? (
        <p>You have succefully create and account </p>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Currently, there's no check for the length of the password. In `isPasswordValid()` function, also check the length of the `password` as well and if its less than 8, return false ----> `if (password.length < 8) return false;`

Comment: Thank you mate but I don't think thats the right answer

Comment: Why do you think that? As far as i understand your code, you are only checking for the password's length when the password field triggers an `onChange` event but there's no similar check when the form is submitted.

Comment: Then I think it will show always `Upps sorry Password did not match`

Comment: I have share my codesandbox code. Could you please show me in code?

Comment: I assume [this is what](https://codesandbox.io/s/password-validation-forked-uluwi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) you want.

Comment: Yes mate.. Thanks a lot 

Comment: How Can I give you accept answer?

Comment: Thanks but no need for that :) Your problem has been solved and that's what matters.

Comment: Thanks a lot .  Keep up the good works

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code on sandbox. You can add an additional check in disabled.

`App.tsx`

```
  <button
        type="submit"
        name="action"
        onClick={onSubmit}
        disabled={!formState.email || formState.password.length < 8}
      >
```